# integrating angular and joint js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jointjs

I am trying to integrate angular with joint js.I have wrapped the joint js content within angular directive but for some reasons, the code is not working.

view contains:

```
 <joint-diagram graph="graph" width="width" height="height" grid-size="1" />
```

Directive:

```
 app.directive('jointDiagram', [function () {

    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            height: '=',
            width: '=',
            gridSize: '=',
            graph: '=',
        }
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        var diagram = newDiagram(scope.height, scope.width, scope.gridSize, scope.graph, element[0]);


    }

    function newDiagram(height, width, gridSize, graph, targetElement) {

        var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
            el: targetElement,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            gridSize: gridSize,
            model: graph,
        });

        return paper;
    }

}]);
```

graph,width and height are passed via a controller.Directive is only rendering the paper object without any nodes(cells)c passed via graph object.But when I print the paper object,it does contain graph object having nodes.what could be the reason behind this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain of the underlying cause of this but since you're adding items to the graph **before** you create your Paper instance, they aren't drawn. You can use `graph.resetCells()` to trigger the redraw. For example, using the Hello World example provided in JointJS;

```
// Create an empty Graph instance and assign to the Paper instance
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph,
    paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: element[0],
        width: scope.width,
        height: scope.height,
        model: graph,
        gridSize: scope.gridSize
    }),
    cells = [];

var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
    attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'A Box', fill: 'white' } }
});

var rect2 = rect.clone();
rect2.translate(300);

var link = new joint.dia.Link({
    source: { id: rect.id },
    target: { id: rect2.id }
});

cells.push(rect, rect2, link);

// Now refresh the graph to ensure the nodes render
graph.resetCells(cells)
```